# Is there a way to ensemble multiple logistic regression equations into one?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, ensemble-learning

I am working on a binary classification problem where the response rate (bads) is less than 1%. The predictors include a set of nominal categorical and continuous variables.

Initially, I experimented with an oversampling technique (SMOTE) to balance the two classes. Logistic regression performed on the oversampled dataset results in good overall accuracy but a very very high false positive rate.

I am now planning to do undersampling and run multiple logistic regression models. The basic python code I am working on is as follows. Need guidance in ensembling results of these multiple logistic regression models into one.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
#Set i for the number of equations required
for i in range(10):
   #Create a sample of goods, good is pandas df containing goods
   sample_good=good.sample(n=300,replace=True)

   #Create a sample of bads, bad is pandas df containing bads. There are 
   #only 100 bads in the dataset
   sample_bad=bad.sample(n=100,replace=True)

   #Append the good and bad sample
   sample=sample_good.append(sample_bad)

   X = sample.loc[:, sample.columns != 'y']
   y = sample.loc[:, sample.columns == 'y']

   from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
   from sklearn import metrics
   X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, 
   random_state=0)
   logreg = LogisticRegression()
   logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
   y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test)
   print('Accuracy of logistic regression classifier on test set: 
   {:.2f}'.format(logreg.score(X_test, y_test)))
```

The above for loop runs 10 times and build 10 different models. Need guidance on ensembling these 10 models into one model. I have read about available techniques like bagging etc. In this case, the sample I create needs to have all the bads each time due to very low response rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use scikit-learn's BaggingClassifier. In short, it fits several classifiers on random subsamples of your data and then has them voting to perform the classification. This meta-estimator will elegantly prevent you from writing a for loop. As for the sampling (which is your original motivation to write the loop I believe), you can adjust weights in the model.fit() method.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import balanced_accuracy_score

breast_cancer = datasets.load_breast_cancer()
X = breast_cancer.data
y = breast_cancer.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y)
```

As you can see, the dataset is imbalanced (after all, it's medical data):

```
len(y_train[y_train == 0]),len(y_train[y_train == 1]) # 163, 263
```

Therefore, let us add sample weights

```
y0 = len(y_train[y_train == 0])
y1 = len(y_train[y_train == 1])

w0 = y1/y0
w1 = 1

sample_weights = np.zeros(len(y_train))
sample_weights[y_train == 0] = w0
sample_weights[y_train == 1] = w1
```

Now the BaggingClassifier:

```
model = BaggingClassifier(LogisticRegression(solver = 'liblinear'), 
                      n_estimators=10, 
                      bootstrap = True, random_state = 2019)
model.fit(X,y,sample_weights)
balanced_accuracy_score(y_test,model.predict(X_test)) # 94.2%
```

Note that if I don't fit with the sample weights, I get only 92.1% balanced accuracy (balanced accuracy = average recall, which is very handy for imbalanced problems)

Comment: Thanks Maxime, I will definitely give it a shot. Couple of further questions, how do the weights work? Does w1=1 means all bads from training set will be selected in each bagging sample? How does w0 = y0/y1 work? How many/what proportion of goods in each bagging sample?

Comment: Suppose you have y0 = 100 and y1 = 200. Let w0 and w1 be the weights of each class. We have to have y0.w0 = y1.w1. Let us arbitrarily set w1 =1 (you can choose any other number as a matter of fact), and then you have w0 = y1/y0.

This means that for each estimator, the random sample (using bootstrap) will be drawn from from your total data using these weights. 

If you want, you can add max_features = 0.5 to the BaggingClassifier function, which will limit to 50% the size of each subsample. But using the weights, it will ensure each subsample has the right distribution

Comment: Thanks Maxime for the explanation.